# Need Django Package for S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am looking for a simple but effective S3 based Django Package through which subscribers from the website can directly use storage services without any hassle. I am a beginner for django so really looking for something simple to use. Please recommend something exactly as per requirement as previously I've found some resources but they cover all storage services and gets complicated for me to understand or apply. I need something that directly stores files to S3 excluding web server layer. I also don't want to save Access Key/Secret Key to my global settings file in settings.py. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

django-storages works quite well and many other Django products rely on it. It does provide other storage services besides S3 but, of course, you don't need to use any of the others.

It does need to know your AWS access key & secret key, but you don't need to actually put those values in your settings.py; typically, you'll put them in an environmental variable and read those in settings.py, like:

> AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
>   AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

Comment: I don't need storage solution embedded for admin...I need it for all my customers. I know about this but this isn't for customers rather for site. What I am looking for is that only customers who subscribe for it will use it and ones who does not need will not have the facility.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you mean by "for admin" versus "for all my customers", but: you can use django-storages for both "static" assets (JS, CSS, etc) and "media" (files uploaded, either in user-facing forms or through the model forms in django's admin). It sounds like you don't want to use S3 for the static stuff, but want to use it for the media stuff--and that's a case that it can handle just fine.